# CakePHP SMTP Connection timed out

Tags: cakephp, smtp, gmail

I know there is a load of questions about this topic, but still can't figure out what is going wrong.

Here's my code:

```
                $this->Email->to = 'any@mailadress.com';
                $this->Email->subject = 'any subject';
                $this->Email->replyTo = 'noreply@mailadress.com';
                $this->Email->from = 'Somebody <noreply@mailadress.com>';
                $this->Email->additionalParams = '-fnoreply@mailadress.com';
                $this->Email->template = 'my_template';
                $this->Email->sendAs = 'text';
                $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
                    'port'=>'465',
                    'timeout'=>'30',
                    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com', // also tried smtp.gmail.com
                    'username'=>'username',
                    'password'=>'pass',
                    );
                $this->Email->send();
```

Now this leads to nothing but "Connection timed out: 110". I tried several other mailing services. Always get the connection error.

Help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I really left that out in my code sample.

I already debugged it and that is when I received the 110 error.

In fact, I managed to set it up properly now. It seems like the provider blocked the ports or something like that, because when I moved it to another server everything worked out fine.

Nevertheless, thanks for your help!

Comment: man I have got the same error, again in another server it works fine, just the problem is I can not move to another server. did u figure out what was the exact problem ? thanks

Comment: Checkout whether a Mail Transfer Agent is installed on your server. Maybe use a plain PHP script (http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-can-i-test-php-mail-functionality) and if it fails, ask your provider.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yeah as it turned out using another smtp account was disallowed. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the delivery method:

```
$this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
```

I think `smtp.gmail.com` is the way you should go - I'm not sure the `ssl` version will work.

The 1.2 manual is much better on this topic (as it is with many others).

Try debugging the code using http://book.cakephp.org/view/1635/Debugging-Emails (or simply `debug(someVar);exit;` at the appropriate place).

Comment: Yeah, I really left that out in my code sample. 

I already debugged it and that is when I received the 110 error. 

In fact, I managed to set it up properly now. It seems like the provider blocked the ports or something like that, because when I moved it to another server everything worked out fine. 

Nevertheless, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check that outgoing connections on port 465 are open on your server. I had the same problem and opened the port solves it.